# Is it worth getting a higher education to work in Europe?

Tags: job-search, work-environment, employment, international

I am considering the prospect of immigration to another country. I myself am from Russia and have a secondary vocational education in the field of IT and almost a year of work in the specialty, now I think to go and get higher education, but I doubt its necessity. The question is: will it make life difficult for me when I immigrate / to apply for a job?

Countries that I consider for immigration: Austria, Italy, Germany, Switzerland, Canada.

if you have a similar experience?

Comment: There might be different requirements for different positions in different countries. I would suggest you to check the education requirements for specific positions you like at for instance Linkedin job search.

Comment: Language is important here, and although good English is a plus, how is your german/italian?

Comment: @Borgh , Italian and German are bad, but I'm considering the prospect. It’s not so long to learn a language, but to get higher education is very long and expensive

Comment: A degree might also be required for immigration purposes, regardless the job description. Check relevant regulations for EU/Canada/Switzerland.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti , if you get a visa of a valuable specialist, then you definitely need to get a higher education, I have no desire to spend time on this. For 5 years, you can acquire more relevant knowledge in self-development.

Comment: Yes, it definitely depends on the type of Visa you apply for but it's somehow _forced_ by the type of job you're looking for (and the field of the company you will work for - and sponsor your Visa). Different Visas have different burdens for the company then you can't really generalize but it's probably easier to get a Visa for an IT position (as specialist) than for - let's say - a job as waiter.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti ? in my country, unfortunately, I did not meet undergraduate with such a short term of study :(

Comment: If you want to get into a job that requires a specific degree, keep in mind that as a rule, foreign degrees are not (easily) transferrable to the country you want to work in. It such a case, it might be easier to get the degree in the country you want to work in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the very short answers:

---

> Is it worth ...

That is very unspecific. Worth from what point of view? Financial? Getting a job? Getting into some research?

> now I think to go and get higher education, but I doubt its necessity. The question is: will it make life difficult for me when I immigrate / to apply for a job?

It is not necessary. You can immigrate. You can apply for a job. But there is no guarantee that you will actually get the said job.

---

Longer answer

Different countries have different regulations. In some countries / companies you CAN NOT have some specific job if you do not have the appropriate degree for that job.

Even if you do not get a university degree, you should still have some certifications for being able to do your job properly.

Just remember: you are not the only guy without a degree who knows the number of buttons on a keyboard. The internet is quite abundant of people asking exactly this kind of question.

If you want to have a better life by immigration, then prepare yourself and maximize your chances to get a good job.